# Doesnt upsert all the records when I execute

Tags: schedulebatch

I tried running a schedule job through anonymous window, it executed but ithasnt upserted all the records. There are 10,000 records and only 8000 were upserted. I see this in the logs -  Exceeded maximum time allotted for callout (120000 ms)
Here is my code-
Batch Class-

```
global class Tlw_BatchCls implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts, Schedulable{
    
    global List<customobj> tlList = new list<customObj>();
    
    global Tlw_BatchCls(){ 
       String fromdt = System.now().addDays(-1).formatGMT('MM-dd-yyyy');
       String toDt = System.now().addDays(-1).formatGMT('MM-dd-yyyy');     
        Boolean isfromBatch = true;
       
        this.tlList = tlw_sync.upsertRecords(fromdt,toDt,isfromBatch);
    } 
    
    global List<customobj> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return tlList;
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<customobj> tl){         
        if(tl.size()>0){            
            Schema.SObjectField tlExtId = customObj.Fields.external_id__c;
            Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(tl, tlExtId);            
        }       
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
      
    }
    
    
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {        
        Tlw_BatchCls batchJob = new Tlw_BatchCls();
        Id batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(batchJob,10);
    }
}
```

Apex class-

```
global class tlw_sync { 
    //I tried to add @future(callout=true) here but it threw an error saying Future methods doesnt support return type of list<customObj
    public static list<customObj> upsertRecords(String fromDt, String toDt, Boolean isFromBatch){     
        List<customObj> tlRecords = new List<customObj>();   
        integer page = 1;        
        integer Size = 100;
        Integer responseSize;
        
           Http http = new Http();
            HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest();           
           
            try{
                do{            
                     string url = 'https://apiSync.com/from_date='+fd+'&to_date='+td+'&page='+page+'&size='+Size;
                  
                    request.setEndpoint(url);                                      
                    request.setHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key',xxxxxxx);
                    request.setMethod('GET');       
                    request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');               
                    request.setTimeout(120000);                    
                    
                    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);                           
                    String responseBody = response.getBody();                                
                    GetResponseBodyClass ParsedResponse = new GetResponseBodyClass();                    
                    ParsedResponse = (GetResponseBodyClass)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, GetResponseBodyClass.class);      
                               
                    
                    Map<String,results> targetResults = new Map<String,results>();
                    Map<string,customObj> targetIds = new Map<string,customObj>();                
                    
                    responseSize = ParsedResponse.results.size();
                    
                    
                    for(Results re : ParsedResponse.results){          
                        targetResults.put(re.uniqueKey, re);               
                    }
                    
                    
                    if(targetResults.keySet().size()>0){                           
                        for(Results re : ParsedResponse.results){             
                            
                            
                            customObj targetLocs = new customObj(
                                                                                     Street_Name__c = re.streetName,
                                                                                    
                                                                                     Address__c = re.street,                                                                                
                                                                                     country__c = re.country,
                                                                                     state__c = re.state,                                                                        
                                                                                     city__c = re.city, 
                                                                                     Zip_Code__c = re.postal,                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                     external_id__c = re.uniqueKey,
                                                                                     
                                                                                    );
                                                
                            tlRecords.add(targetLocs);                
                                          
                        }                     
                        
                    }                
                    page++;
                   
                } while(responseSize == Size);                 
                
            }
            catch(exception e){           
            }
       }
        return tlRecords;
    }   
    
    
    public class GetResponseBodyClass {
        public Integer total;
        public Integer page;
        public List<Results> results;
    } 
    
    public class Results {
       
        public String street;
        public String country;
        public String state;
        public String city;
        public String postal;               
        public String uniqueKey;      
            
    }    
   
}
```

Comment: What is your question? The error seems pretty straightforward; you'll have to change how you're calling this remote API  (perhaps a smaller page size?) to ensure your requests are performant.

Comment: I did try with smaller size as well but no luck. Currently the size is 100, I tried reducing it to 75 and 50 but it still throws the same error-  Exceeded maximum time allotted for callout (120000 ms)

Comment: Then you may need to speak to the support team for your remote API, since it's failing to return a response in 2 minutes!